# How to limit the display of the content div json to three

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

How can I limit the display of the content div JSON to three? Now the code shows all the items downloaded from JSON. I would like to only return 3 divs.

```
<div id="p"></div>
```

```js
$.getJSON('element.json', function(data){
    var a = data.i;
    var d = $("<div class='p1'>");
    var ele = '';
    $.each(a,function(i,v){
        ele += "<div class='k'>"+ v.num + "</div>";
    });
    d.html(ele);
    $("#p").append(a);
});
```

```js
{
    "i":[{
        "num": "1",
    },{
        "num": "1",
    },{
        "num": "3"
    },{
        "num": "4"
    },{
        "num": "5",
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you only want to retrieve 3 elements from the array you could use `slice()`:

```
var a = data.i.slice(0, 3);
```

Answer (score 2):

This could be limited in the if statement to ensure the index doesn't exceed 2.

```
$.each(a,function(i,v){
    if (i>=3){
       return false;
    }
    ele += "<div class='k'>"+ v.num + "</div>";
});
```